# Are these images too 'noisy' to be correctly classified by a CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, neural-network

I'm attempting to build an image classifier to identify between 2 types of images on property sites. I've split my dataset into 2 categories: [Property, Room]. I'm hoping to be able to differentiate between whether the image is of the outside of some property or a room inside the property.

Below are 2 examples of the types of image I am using. My dataset consists of 800 images for each category, and then a training set of an additional 160 images for each category (not present in the training set).

I always seem to be get reasonable results in training, but then when I test against some real samples it usually ends up classifying all of the images into a single category.

Below you can see the model I am using:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    rotation_range=10,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
) # set validation split

validate_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

IMG_HEIGHT = IMG_WIDTH = 128
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (11,11), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3), padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(11, 11),
    # tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    # Second convolutional layer
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (11, 11), padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(11, 11),
    # tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    # Flattening
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    # Full connection
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model.compile(
    optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# now train the model
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=75, #100
    epochs=5, # 15, or 20, and 100 steps per epoch
    validation_steps=50,
    verbose=1
)

# Predict image
def load_image(img_path, show=False):
  test_image = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH))
  test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
  test_image /= 255.
  test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
  return test_image

def predict_image(img_path, show=False):
  loaded_img = load_image(img_path, show)
  pred = model.predict(loaded_img)
  return 'property' if pred[0][0] == 0.0 else 'room'

print('Prediction is...')
print(predict_image('path/to/my/img')
```

Can anyone suggest the possible reasons for this? I've tried using different epochs and batch sizes, augmenting the images further, changing the Conv2D and Pooling layer size but nothing seems to help.

Do I perhaps not have enough data, or are they bad images to begin with? This is my first foray into ML so apologies if any of questions seem obvious.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How exactly are you predicting on the new images? Are you normalizing these images the same way as the training set?

Comment: Yes, i'm using data augmentation initially, and then my new images are the same size as my training set, just not augmented in any way.

Comment: I am not talking about data augmentation, but for example, division by 255 to make the images in the [0, 1] range. Are you doing that? Maybe just include code that defines the generator.

Comment: Yes, i've updated my code samples. I'm scaling by 1/255. I suspect that maybe there's something wrong with my prediction code?

Comment: The image loading code looks fine, but I don't like that you are comparing the probability with 0.0, that will not work, Keras uses a threshold of 0.5 to decide which class to output, first class if probability < 0.5, and second class otherwise, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Yep i just read a similar comment on another thread. I thought that the binary classifier would output 0/1. Turns out as you said it's a rang 0-1 so i'm now using `(pred > 0.5).astype(int)` to classify. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not post-processing the output of the classifier correctly, it outputs a probability in [0, 1], with `values < 0.5` corresponding to the first class, and `values >= 0.5` for the second class. You should change the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I just discovered this the same time you posted your answer, I assumed the output was a binary value, not a val between 0-1.

Answer (score -1):

Try Data Augmentation: it augments the image to some random transformations like Random Rotation, Random Zoom, Random Horizontal Flip, width shift and height shift. And also try to implement Batch Normalisation.